post request suddenly fail due to "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"
i have an php file on a webspace starting with:
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Content-Type:application/json");

now i have a react site(on a different server) that uses get requests from that file with
export const queryPHP = (f, d, callback, errorCB=null) => {
    let data = {...d}
    let url = urlForQuery + '?f=' + f;
    for(let key in data) url += "&" + key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
    console.log(url)
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {

            if(json.success) callback(json.data);
            else {
                if(errorCB == null) console.log(json.data)
                else errorCB(json.data);
            }
        })
}

and it works fine. I also do post requests to it using
export const postPHP = (f, data, callback, errorCB=null) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    for(let key in data) {
        formData.append(key, data[key])
    }
    let url = urlForQuery + '?f=' + f;
    fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    body: formData
  })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {

            if(json.success) callback(json.data);
            else {
                if(errorCB == null) console.log(json.data)
                else errorCB(json.data);
            }
        });
}

which used to work, but suddenly produces the error

Access to fetch at 'https://...' from origin 'https://...' has been
blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
CORS disabled.

I don't understand what has changed. Can anyone help me solve this?

I think the error message is quite clear: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present". So the first thing to do is to check the response headers in the developer tools, is that header indeed absent? Probably. Why would your browser lie? Next thing is then to find out why that header is absent, even though you think it is there. Maybe a redirect? A bug in your code?

but suddenly...things don't change randomly - computers are good at being consistent. Have there been any changes in the environment where this is happening? e.g. code updates, server changes, updates, upgrades, deletions, etc etc? And as KIKO says, the error is clear - so go and investigate what's really happening to the request, using your browser's tools. Also maybe look for things like errors in the PHP code (you should have PHP error logging enabled hopefully??) which might cause it not to output the headers.
